# Image Browser in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I want to make an image browser for my application where the user can select the image that he wants from the phone. I am reading each image from the phone like this:

```
FileConnection fileConnection = (FileConnection)Connector.open((String) imm.elementAt(i));
InputStream inputStream = fileConnection.openInputStream();
byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int)fileConnection.fileSize()];
inputStream.read(imageBytes);
inputStream.close();
fileConnection.close();

EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageBytes, 0, -1);
EncodedImage image1 = scaleImageEncoded.scaleImage(image, (int) (Display.getWidth() / 4) - 10, (int) (Display.getWidth() / 4) - 10);
BrowseBitmapField field = (BrowseBitmapField) manager.getField(i);
field.setBitmap(image1.getBitmap());
field.setEncodedImage(image);
```

When the phone included many images, this process bicomes too slow and the phone needs a lot of time to get them. Is there any faster way to read an image from the memory of the phone and display it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guy who posted at the below URL figured out you can get the thumbnail from BBThumbs.dat and posted some code. I haven't tried it myself but if it works the time savings should be very significant.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Thumbnails-work-around/td-p/343870

Comment: Where can i find the BBThubms.dat? I searched everywhere and in each directory containing images and could not find it

Comment: try \BlackBerry\system\media on the internal memory and \appdata\rim\media, that's where they live on my BB

Comment: but those two folders are hidden ... how to read their content then!! An exception that the file is not found is thrown when using fileConnection.openInputStream(); to read the file

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what `jprofitt` recommends I'd suggest to do the following:

1. When you create a resized version of an image you can save it for future usages. Next time user clicks on the same image you first check for a resized image presence and if not present only then read/resize the original image. So you can save time spent on future resizing + don't forget that resized image file size is in times smaller than original, so future reading will happen in times faster.
2. Do not try to read/resize all images in the dir at once. Do this only for those that should be visible for the user at the moment. For instance, if the the dir has 100 images you'll most likely need A LOT of time to read/resize/attach to manager all images. However user sees just 6 or 8 images on the screen at a time. If user scrolls up/down, then it's right time to request reading/resizing/etc for those images that now should be visible, but have not been read/resized yet.
3. Reading/resizing should be done on a background `Thread` in order not to block the main UI-thread. In other words user should be able to scroll the screen while reading/resizing happens on a background `Thread`. I recommend to arrange a queue of reading/resizing tasks and execute them on a background worker `Thread`. When a task is done on worker `Thread` and it's time to update UI of the screen with resized image, then use `UiApplication.invokeLater(Runnable action)` for that.

Comment: Hey arhimed ... All what you said is done before. I am saving the original encoded image for future use and I am not resizing all the pictures at once and the work is done in a thread for sure using the invoke later. But this is slow that's why I posted here so we can find a better solution. Did you tried to make an image browser urslef?

Comment: Yes, in one of the projects there was such a component. We got images from server and then had to arrage image browser for it. I remember we resized the downloaded image right after the download, so by the time of reading/showing it in image browser we already had a resized image.

Comment: Yes but this is not the case. Here I am reading them from the device memory. The problem is that the time that each file takes to be readed is too much. I want to minimize this time. Downloading images and getting them as byte is not my case because here I am reading bytes from the phone which is too slow.

Answer (score 2):

You may try using a BufferedInputStream. I've had luck with it speeding up my read times, might work for you as well.

```
 BufferedInputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileConnection.openInputStream());
 byte[] imageBytes = new byte[(int)fileConnection.fileSize()];
 inputStream.read(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

Comment: Hey jprofitt, I am trying your code. I can see the BufferedInputStream in the APIs of blackberry but when I import it into the JDE 6.0 it is telling me that there is no "java.io.BufferedInputStream" !!! I cant find it in the import neither!! how to use this? It is the first time I see this issue

Comment: That is an interesting question. I looked in the API and did some poking around and apparently it isn't included in the 6.0 OS

Comment: If you don't need anything from 6.0, you could just compile for 5.0

Comment: Well I successfully used the BBThumbs.dat and the thumbs.dat. Try it you will be amazed by its speed. You can load up to 100 images for a time of 1 minute only. But still not complete with me i am working on it to make it faster